# Android - Best practice to update ListView

Tags: android, listview

Here is my adapter

```
lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.vlist);
adapter = new TestAdapter(context, R.id.vlist, data); 
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I popular **data** in an **AsyncTask class**. So where is the best place I should call:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I think I will pass **adapter** as a parameter into **AsyncTask instance** and call data changed in **onPostExecute**. Is it the best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only showing your list at the end call notifyDataSetChanged() in onPostExecute().

Comment: What is the best practice to call notifyDataSetChanged in onPostExecute?

Comment: Yes it is, because its called on the UI thread when its background processing is done.